Role is invalid or cannot be assumed, when I add Transform: AWS::Include to the cloudformation template
I am getting the following error when I try to add Transform: AWS::Include to read TableMappings for the DMS task in cloudformation template.
Failed to create the changeset: Waiter ChangeSetCreateComplete failed: Waiter encountered a terminal failure state: For expression "Status" we matched expected path: "FAILED" Status: FAILED. Reason: Role arn:aws:iam::xxxxxxxxxx:role/cloudformation-deployment-role is invalid or cannot be assumed

Template deployment works fine when I add the TableMappings json inline in the template as below.
      TableMappings: |
          {
            "rules": [
              {
                "rule-type": "selection",
                "rule-id": "1",
                "rule-name": "1",
                "object-locator": {
                  "schema-name": "TEST",
                  "table-name": "TEST_TABLE"
                },
                "rule-action": "include",
                "filters": []
              }

But when I change the TableMappings to use Transform: AWS::Include to read json from s3 file I am getting the above error.
      TableMappings:
        Fn::Transform:
          Name: AWS::Include
          Parameters:
            Location: !Sub s3://${BucketName}/dms/table-mappings.json

Anyone has idea what could be causing this?
Role and Policies used:
  CloudformationDeploymentRole:
    Type: AWS::IAM::Role
    Properties:
      RoleName: cloudformation-deployment-role
      Path: /
      AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
        Version: 2012-10-17
        Statement:
        - Effect: Allow
          Principal:
            Service:
            - cloudformation.amazonaws.com
          Action:
          - sts:AssumeRole
          Condition:
            StringEquals:
              aws:SourceAccount: !Ref AWS::AccountId

  DevOpsArtifactsPolicy:
    Type: AWS::IAM::ManagedPolicy
    Properties:
      Path: /
      ManagedPolicyName: artifact-retrieval-policy
      Roles:
        - !Ref CloudformationDeploymentRole
      PolicyDocument:
        Version: 2012-10-17
        Statement:
        - Sid: S3Access
          Effect: Allow
          Action:
            - s3:Get*
            - s3:*
          Resource:
            - !Sub arn:aws:s3:::${ArtifactsBucketName}
            - !Sub arn:aws:s3:::${ArtifactsBucketName}/*
        - Sid: AccessKMSkey
          Effect: Allow
          Action:
            - kms:DescribeKey
            - kms:GenerateDataKey
            - kms:Encrypt
            - kms:ReEncrypt*
            - kms:Decrypt
          Resource:
            - !Ref DevOpsKmsArn

  CloudformationDeployPolicy:
    Type: AWS::IAM::ManagedPolicy
    Properties:
      Path: /
      ManagedPolicyName: cloudformation-deploy-policy
      Roles:
      - !Ref CloudformationDeploymentRole
      PolicyDocument:
        Version: 2012-10-17
        Statement:
        - Effect: Allow
          Action:
            - iam:*Policy*
            - iam:CreateRole
            - iam:GetRole
            - iam:TagRole
            - iam:UntagRole
          Resource:
            - !Sub arn:aws:iam::${AWS::AccountId}:role/dms-vpc-role
        - Sid: WildcardActions
          Action:
          - ec2:DeleteTags
          - secretsmanager:GetRandomPassword
          - secretsmanager:CreateSecret
          - rds:DescribeEngineDefaultParameters
          Effect: Allow
          Resource: "*"
        - Sid: DMS
          Action:
            - dms:*ReplicationSubnetGroup
            - dms:AddTagsToResource
            - dms:*Endpoint
            - dms:CreateReplicationInstance
            - dms:DescribeReplicationInstances
            - dms:*ReplicationTask*
            - dms:ListTagsForResource
          Effect: Allow
          Resource:
            - !Sub arn:aws:dms:${AWS::Region}:${AWS::AccountId}:*:*

  CloudformationDeployPolicy:
    Type: AWS::IAM::ManagedPolicy
    Properties:
      Path: /
      ManagedPolicyName: cloudformation-deploy-policy
      Roles:
      - !Ref CloudformationDeploymentRole
      PolicyDocument:
        Version: 2012-10-17
        Statement:
        - Sid: UpdateCfn
          Action:
            - cloudformation:CreateChangeSet
          Effect: Allow
          Resource:
            - !Sub arn:aws:cloudformation:${AWS::Region}:aws:transform/Include
        - Sid: SsmParamPermissions
          Effect: Allow
          Action:
            - ssm:GetParameter*
            - ssm:PutParameter
            - ssm:DeleteParameter
            - ssm:AddTagsToResource
            - ssm:RemoveTagsFromResource
          Resource:
            - !Sub arn:aws:ssm:${AWS::Region}:${AWS::AccountId}:parameter/*
        - Sid: VpcPermissions
          Effect: Allow
          Action:
            - ec2:CreateSecurityGroup
            - ec2:DeleteSecurityGroup
            - ec2:AuthorizeSecurityGroup*
            - ec2:CreateTags
            - ec2:DescribeVpcs
            - ec2:DescribeSubnets
            - ec2:DescribeSecurityGroups
            - ec2:DescribeAvailabilityZones
          Resource: '*'


Is cloudformation-deployment-role the name of the role used by CloudFormation? Do you/the pipeline whatever is triggering the Stack create/update have permission to assume that role? It may well be that the issue is not related to your mapping.

Yes it is. And it has the trust relation as shown above to allow cloudformation to assume. I use the CLI command for cloudformation deploy with role flag. As mentioned it works fine when I remove the AWS::Include

When you're using the Include, Cloudformation tries to access the file. So it's mostly a permission with that role. Are you sure that the specified cloudformation role has access to that bucket? And there's no additional bucket ACL or policy issue?

yes. The role has both S3 and KMS permissions. The error indicates assume role issue though. Trust relation is also there

Can you share you role, so i can try it on my end also

I added the Role and polices used
